# Hosting code for an open source social media website

Tags: php, github, open-source, social-media

I'm building a social media network and I want to make the code publicly available so that anyone can contribute.
Can I use GitHub for this purpose?
Also, how do I decide which files should be hosted on the GitHub repository?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Github or Bitbucket.

On which files should be on hosted on Github,

1. You should never have configuration files in your codebase.
2. You should not have node_modules

Based on the framework and technology stack you select, you can create your `.gitignore` file using https://www.gitignore.io/ to ensure that you don't commit configuration files, environment files, etc.

Comment: So, if I'm not mistaken, the configuration files include the connection variables for the database, right?

Comment: Yes, and those connection variables should be defined in environment variables which are outside Github.

Comment: And what about the password encryption and machine learning modules? My apologies if it all sounds too naive, but I'm not very experienced in this field.